# How to grep for the next instance of a variable in a logfile?

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, grep

So I am trying to parse FTP logs and see if a certain user is logging in securely. So far I have this to pull the next couple of lines after the user logs in

```
cat proftpd.log.2 | grep -B 3 "USER $sillyvariable"
```

and this is a sample output it creates

```
::ffff:127.0.0.0 UNKNOWN ftp [04/Jan/2013:11:03:06 -0800] "AUTH TLS" 234 -
::ffff:127.0.0.0 UNKNOWN ftp [04/Jan/2013:11:03:06 -0800] "USER $sillyvariable" 331 -
```

Now this is a perfect example of what I want, it displays the **AUTH TLS** Message and the **IPs match**. However this is not always the case as many users are constantly logging in and out and most of the time the output is jumbled.

Is there a way I can grep for the `USER $sillyvariable` and find his/her matched IP containing the "AUTH TLS" in the preceding line so I can know they logged in securely? I guess you can say I want to grep the user and then grep backwards to see if the connection they originated from (matching IPs) was secure. I'm kind of stuck on this and could really use some help.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you do two greps - the first looks for the user, the next looks for the previous line **in just the lines that matched**

Comment: This would be fairly trivial in Perl, if you're open to that sort of thing. It might be a good exercise to learn the language if you don't already...

Comment: @Floris Can you elaborate with an example for me? I understand your logic  but I am not quite sure how to do so. Thanks.

Comment: @JonahBishop I am currently a Jr. SysAdmin and open to learn anything that might help me out in the long run, could you give me a basic example of how to do this? I tried in PHP using strrpos() but things just got way too complicated. I figured there had to be an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ grep -B3 'USER $sillyvariable' proftpd.log.2 |
  tac | awk 'NR==1 {IP=$1} $1==IP {print}' | tac
::ffff:127.0.0.0 UNKNOWN ftp [04/Jan/2013:11:03:06 -0800] "AUTH TLS" 234 -
::ffff:127.0.0.0 UNKNOWN ftp [04/Jan/2013:11:03:06 -0800] "USER $sillyvariable" 331 -
```

This uses `tac` to reverse the lines in the grep result. It then looks for all lines where the IP addresses match the one in the `USER` line. Finally it runs `tac` again to put the lines back in the original order.

Comment: You are a genius my friend. I've never even heard of `tac` before. Thank you so much and thanks for editing my post correctly, long time lurker on Stack Overflow and finally made an account today because I couldn't find a solution on here without asking. Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure this works if another line "sneaks in" in the logfile... what if the AUTH statement wasn't in the three preceding lines? I think you need to reprocess the entire logfile once you have found the IP address of the user. But maybe I misunderstood the problem statement - the OP accepted this as the correct answer...

Comment: @Floris Agreed, the `-B3` is not robust. A robust solution would be quite a bit hairier. You would also have to make sure the preceding AUTH matches *this* USER line, that there wasn't another USER line somewhere in between.

Comment: I am actually looking for instances where the **AUTH** does not show up so I can mail an alert to myself that the user has logged incorrectly. So the only flaw I see in this is that I cant make something like B* or B*/* if you catch my flow. However, I don't believe it will ever be over a hundred lines back. If there is a solution to just have it `grep -B'the_entire_file'` then that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I realize I am very late to this party, but the comment I made about the AUTH statement possibly being more than 3 lines earlier left me wondering.

I took a slightly different approach, in which I make minimal assumptions (based on limited knowledge of the contents of your log file):

1. There is one user per IP address (may not be true if they are behind a firewall)
2. For every AUTH entry there should be exactly one "good" USER entry from the same IP address
3. A sorted list of IP addresses which have entries in the log file will show more "USER" than "AUTH" requests for any IP address from which a "bad" request was made

If those assumptions are reasonable / true, then a simple bash script does quite a nice job of giving you exactly what you want (which is a list of the users that didn't log in properly - which is not exactly what you were asking for):

```
#!/bin/bash
# first, find all the "correct" IP addresses that did the login "right", and sort by IP address:
grep -F "AUTH TLS" $1 | awk '{print $1}' | sort > goodLogins

# now find all the lines in the log file with USER and sort by IP address
grep USER $1 | awk '{print $1}' | sort > userLogins

# now see if there were user logins that didn't correspond to a "good" login:
echo The following lines in the log file did not have a corresponding AUTH statement:
echo
sdiff goodLogins userLogins | grep "[<>]" | awk '{print $2 ".*USER"}' > badUsers
grep -f badUsers $1
echo -----
```

Note that this leaves you with three temporary files (goodLogins, userLogins, badUsers) which you might want to remove. I assume you know how to create a text file with the above code, set it to be executable ( `chmod u+x scrubLog` ), and run it with the name of the log file as parameter ( `./scrubLog proftpd.log.2` ).

Enjoy!

PS - I am not sure what you mean by "logging in correctly", but there are other ways to enforce good behaviors. For example, you could block port 21 so only sftp (port 22) requests come through, you could block anonymous ftp, ... But that's not what you were asking about.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I always love finding other solutions to problems and this one is great. By 'logging in correctly' I meant having an AUTH TLS matching their IP and datestamp within the same minute in order to reduce false positives. And as for blocking port 21, that was my first suggestion to my employer, however we cannot implement that rule for unknown reasons to me. Thanks again though!